# Creating an executable jar of selenium test from a maven project

Tags: testing, maven, selenium, automated-tests, executable

I have several selenium tests as part of my project (project X). I would like to be able to create an executable jar which will run the tests, say against a production environment rather than either local or part of the CI build. These will be run periodically to ensure that the current live behaviour of the application matches that of the point of release. For example, it calls to a number of webapps which are deployed separately and their output may change before an update is release of project X.

Ideally I would like to use something like the assembly plugin to create this as part of the build but I am open to other suggestions. Currently the only thing I can think of is to checkout the project on some machine and execute the build as required.

Comment: I've not got a good answer for this and right now am using a hacked together groovy script which packs the tests and necessary dependencies in to a jar with an executable class that simple calls out to a generated Ant script contained in the jar. This Ant script executes the tests and saves the output to a directory

Comment: I'm looking into this too. When you say *I have several selenium tests as part of my project* do you mean proper Maven test? I guess in that case, packing them in the normal build won't be an option, because the tests are to be run by Maven itself (but I may be wrong, I'm a Maven beginner). Anyway, did you try to run your tests through the failsafe plugin? And then parse the report XML in some way?

Comment: Just a two-minutes search: did you ever tried [Maven Embedder](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/maven-embedder/) and / or [Maven Invoker](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/)? Maybe they could help here somehow. I think that to do what you are trying to do, Maven has to be a dependency of the project that contains your tests, or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Never been a fan of using unit testing frameworks to run selenium (as they aren't unit tests) so tend to use a custom framework to output results and to define configuration etc.

Assuming your selenium tests are well structured it should be easy to strip these out into a new project and wrap a framework round to control everything and also output results.

If using as part of CI you can also just run as a downstream executable which will give you a more accurate lifecycle - build, unit test, integration test, deploy, end-to-end test / UI test.

Combinations of the above should give you the flexibility to run as part of CI and also ad-hoc against different deployed systems.

Comment: Hmm... is that actually an answer to the question?

Comment: @AndrewBarber OK my first answer, give me a break :) I thought it did answer the question with a bit of context around not running selenium as a unit test and creating a test project (i.e. executable jar of selenium tests), but using a custom framework to replace junit (or whatever)

Comment: I was just wondering; it wasn't obvious to me how it was an answer to the question, so I asked :)

Comment: Thanks but this really doesn't answer the question. I want to reuse the existing test. They already sit in separate module to the main project as part of a multi-module build. I don't think there's any real benefit of writing a custom framework to execute the tests when surefire+junit works perfectly well.

Comment: OK fair enough. I believe that's the best approach overall and you did say you are open to other suggestions!